# Storing Value from Randomized Function in Model Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Trying to create a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game using C# and MVC. Currently, the user can enter a value into a `textbox` successfully. I have the result from the textbox getting returned by using the following line of code: `<h3>Your Guess:</h3> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UsersGuess)`

My issue is with storing the randomized value in the`ComputerGuess` model property. I created a `ComputerGuess()` method in my Business class, but not sure how to assign this random number. Any help would be appreciated!

**View**

```
@using RockPaperScissors.Business
@model RockPaperScissors.Models.Game

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Games";
}

<h2>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Game"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Enter your decision:</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UsersGuess, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })


    </div>

    <div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Guess" />
    </div>
}

<h3>Your Guess:</h3> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UsersGuess)
<h3>Computers Guess: </h3> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ComputersGuess)
```

**Controller**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RockPaperScissors.Models;

namespace RockPaperScissors.Controllers
{
    public class GameController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Game
        public ActionResult Index(Game userInput)
        {
            return View(userInput);
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace RockPaperScissors.Models
{
    public class Game
    {
        public string UsersGuess { get; set; }
        public int ComputersGuess { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Business Layer**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using RockPaperScissors.Models;

namespace RockPaperScissors.Business
{
    public class ComputerLogic
    {
        public int ComputersGuess()
        {
            List<string> options = new List<string> { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };

            var randomizer = new Random();
            var random = randomizer.Next(options.Count);

            var getRandomValue = new Game
            {
                ComputersGuess = random
            };

            return getRandomValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit unclear - wouldn't you want to have the `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ComputersGuess)` method display either "Rock", "Paper" or "Scissors" rather than an `int`?

Comment: At this point, I was planning on just using their position value to do the logic. I might change that later, but biggest issue is that I can't get that random number and store it in the property.

Comment: Currently you method declares a return type of `int` but you trying to return `Game`. It should be just `return random;`. Then in controller, use `model.ComputersGuess = ComputersGuess();` to set the value

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm still a little confused. Where does `model` come from in the controller. Could you expand on how the controller should look? I'm assuming these changes are going to be made in the `Index` Controller method.

Comment: You GET method should not have a parameter which is a complex object - it should be `public ActionResult Index() { Game model = new Game() { ComputersGuess = ComputersGuess(); return View(model); }`

Comment: But its a bit odd why you have a textbox to enter the UserGuess but also have a `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UsersGuess)` which will only ever display the initial value of `UsersGuess` - which as it is will be `null`

Comment: Apologies for all of the questions. Why can't I access `ComputerGuess()` in the controller? Based on your response, I'm assuming `return model` should be outside of `Game model = new Game {...};` right? My `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserGuess)` is only there to make sure that my value is getting stored in the property correctly. I'll be removing that shortly.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice its in a different class. It would need to be `ComputersGuess = new ComputerLogic().ComputersGuess();` (and you might need to include the namespace as well. Although have a static method and just using `ComputersGuess = ComputerLogic.ComputersGuess()` might be better. (and yes, I missed a closing `}` after `ComputersGuess();`)

Comment: Thanks for all the help @StephenMuecke, I can now generate the random number. I'm assuming that my `UserGuess` is also getting stored even though I can't display it on my `HTML` page right?

Comment: It will be set in the POST method assuming you have `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Index(Game userInput) {...}` but I'm not really sure what your actually wanting to do with it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all of your help... Mainly wanted the `Post` method for testing purposes.